# WordPress сортировка по произвольным полям

Tags: php, wordpress

Прошу помочь разобраться с сортировкой, Мне нужно, чтобы при условии `$_SESSION['sort_opoz']=='rate'`, после сортировки по произвольному полю `ratings_average`, происходила сортировка по второму произвольному полю `ratings_users`, до сортировки по `date`.

Вот код:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sort_opoz'])){
if ($_SESSION['sort_opoz']=='date'){
    $args['orderby'] = 'date';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
}
elseif ($_SESSION['sort_opoz']=='rate'){
    $args['meta_key'] = 'ratings_average';
    //ratings_users
    //$args['meta_query'] = array('ratings_users' => array('key' => 'ratings_users', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'));
    $args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' );
    $args['order'] = '';
}
}

$args['meta_query'] = array(array('key' => 'mroom_detected', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'));
if (isset($_SESSION['opoz'])){
if ($_SESSION['opoz']=='neopoz'){
    $args['meta_query'] = array(array('key' => 'mroom_detected', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'));
}
elseif ($_SESSION['opoz']=='opozn'){
    $args['meta_query'] = array(array('key' => 'mroom_detected', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'));
}
}

$posts = query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сортировки по несколькоким произвольным полям в `meta_query` должен быть ассоциативный массив.

```
$args['meta_query']['mroom_detected'] = array('key' => 'mroom_detected', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS');
if (isset($_SESSION['sort_opoz'])){
    if ($_SESSION['sort_opoz']=='date') {
        $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    } elseif ($_SESSION['sort_opoz']=='rate') {
        $args['meta_query']['ratings_average'] = array('key' => 'ratings_average', 'compare' => 'EXISTS');
        $args['meta_query']['ratings_users'] = array('key' => 'ratings_users', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'EXISTS');
        $args['orderby'] = array( 'ratings_average' => 'DESC', 'ratings_users' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' );
     }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['opoz'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['opoz']=='opozn' ){
        $args['meta_query']['mroom_detected'] = array('key' => 'mroom_detected', 'type' => 'numeric', 'compare' => 'EXISTS');
    }
}
```

> Сортировка по нескольким meta-полям работает в Wordpress начиная с
>   версии 4.2.